# Checkstyle doesn't work with SuppressionCommentFilter

Tags: checkstyle

Below is my code around check style - but it doesnt seem to suppress the audits between the suppression comment lines. I also tried with inline comment // instead of /* */

Please help. I have trying a lot of ways - permutation/combinations of those to get this fixed. Thank you.
Please let me know if you need more info.

```
/* CHECKSTYLE:OFF */
private abc createTimerChart(String title, String yAxisLabel, XYDataset dataset) {
    final abc chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title, // chart title
            "Time Elapsed (" + pollUnit.toString() + ")", // x axis label
            yAxisLabel, // y axis label
            dataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, // include legend
            true, // tooltips
            false // urls
            );
/* CHECKSTYLE:ON */
```

CONFIG.XML reads:

```
    <module name="FileContentsHolder">
        <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
            <property name="checkFormat" value="IndentationCheck"/>
        </module>
    </module>
```

AFTER MOVING SuppressionCommentFilter UNDER CHECKER:

```
<module name="Checker">

<!-- setting the default severity to warning -->
<property name="severity" value="warning" />

<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
    <property name="checkFormat" value="Indentation"/>
</module>

<!-- No TAB characters in the source code -->
<module name="FileTabCharacter" />

<!-- List of files to ignore . -->
<!-- TODO Add all auto-generated files to this file -->
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="checkstyle/kepler-checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
<module name="TreeWalker">
..
..
..
```

Answer (score 2):

The indentation check is called `Indentation`. It shold work if you change the `checkFormat` property to just `Indentation`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="warning" />
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="JavadocType" />
        <module name="Indentation" />
        <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
        <property name="checkFormat" value="Indentation" />
    </module>
</module>
```

Or, more generally, I would recommend not setting the `checkFormat` property at all, which will make the suppression comment suppress *all* warnings for that block of code.

Comment: I had tried that too but it didn't help. Tried again and still no luck :(

Comment: Dang, I tried it, too, and it worked. Hmpf. The only other difference I can see is the fact that your outer module is `FileContentsHolder` instead of `Checker`. If that doesn't help either, can you provide a link to the full config file and a description of how you're calling it? Maybe it's a non-ascii character in the config file or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that too and moved it under only the checker tag but didn't help. Below is my change:

Comment: Updated code snippet in the main question with appropriate formatting

Comment: What version of checkstyle are you using? Can you describe how you are calling it? Via command line, ant task, ...?

Comment: The version is 2.9.1 and I have included it as a reporting plugin for now which would be changed to a build one once all the existing warnings/errors are fixed. Its being invoked with 'mvn clean site' from  the terminal

Comment: Okay, I have pasted my complete config.xml into my answer above. This definitely works for me with your code example. Note the exact position of all the elements, including `FileContentsHolder`.